# DNS setting | Website inaccessible during development

Tags: dns, web

Have a new website coming up and have registered a new domain for it. Till the time development is in progress want the website to be accessible only via specific IPs. How can i make this setting at Domain setting level.

Answer (score 0):

"Domain settings" have nothing to do with restricting access, that's the job of the web server. I see two options:

1. Configure your web server to only allow access from certain IPs.
2. Keep the DNS configuration entirely local; e.g. only configure your local intranet DNS server to resolve this domain, or perhaps just your local hosts file. This way there is no global resolver for this domain at all and only a certain small number of explicitly configured clients.